# Wired connection switching from "connecting" to "cable unplugged" in 20.04

Tags: networking, ethernet, wired

I have just made the switch to Ubuntu on my desktop, and I'm having a network problem that I'm not seeing in other threads.

I have an ethernet cable plugged in--it is the same cable that was being used previously, so I know the connection works--but in the Network settings, the Wired connection keeps switching on, trying to connect for a few seconds, and then switching back to "cable unplugged"

I'm trying to install net-tools to work on the issue, but I'm receiving the following error:

E: Unable to locate package net-tool.

Attempts to update my package lists are also failing.

If anyone can help a poor newbie out, I'd be very grateful.

**edited***

Thanks for the reply
Here's what I get with sudo lshw -C network

cm@Fidget:~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for cm:

*-network

```
   description: Ethernet interface

   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller

   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.

   physical id: 0

   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0

   logical name: enp4s0

   version: 15

   serial: 24:4b:fe:5b:1e:c9

   capacity: 1Gbit/s

   width: 64 bits

   clock: 33MHz

   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation

   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII

   resources: irq:37 ioport:f000(size=256) memory:f7604000-f7604fff memory:f7600000-f7603fff
```

cm@Fidget:~$

I'm using CAT6 cable connected directly to the modem/router.  It's a Motorola MG7315.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network`. Describe your network cabling from the computer, all the way to the router/modem. Are you using cat 5e or cat 6 cables?

Comment: @heynnema okay, it's been updated

Comment: Your cable doesn't look like it's plugged in, or you've got a bad cable, or you've got a bad RJ45 connector on the computer or on the cable modem. Try a different LAN port on the router.

Comment: @heynnema thanks.  I'll try with a different cable/port and let you know if that works.

Comment: Follow up: it was the cable.  once I replaced it with a CAT5, everything worked just fine.  thanks @heynnema

Comment: Thanks for the update! Glad it's all working for you now!